# How to get Blutooth hardware version form android device

Tags: android, bluetooth, hardware

I want to know my Smartphone Bluetooth hardware version thats the device using. Is there any way to get the **Bluetooth hardware version** using adb command or anything else (without spec).

Answer (score 0):

> **You cannot determine Bluetooth version.**

But you can determine

> - Normal Bluetooth or
> - Bluetooth Low Energy

**Using this code:**

```
 PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager(); 
 boolean isBT = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH); 
 boolean isBLE = pm.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE);
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the hardware information from a Bluetooth chipset you normally use the **Read Local Version Information** HCI command. Found a function for it in **hci.c**:

```
int hci_read_local_version(int dd, struct hci_version *ver, int to)
{
    ...
```

Not sure if this function is available in adb, but perhaps you could write a little program?